# install xmlto on linux fetch many packages

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, dependencies, awesome

I want to install the `xmlto` application to generate man pages.
It is a dependency for the awesome wm (3.5) when building it from sources.
When I install `xmlto`

```
apt-get install xmlto
# Need to get 579 MB/906 MB of archives. After unpacking 1 439 MB will be used
# 906 mb Oo !!!!
```

Why so much? Why does `xmlto` have dependencies like ruby, python and others?

Comment: Have you a just installed system? If this true, then it's normal. Also you can have a very basic installation. Commands 'aptitude show xmlto' or 'apt-cache showpkg xmlto' display package dependencies. There is not so much.

Comment: it is true, I just install the system.